# Jquery/Json - How can I get the last <P> in this JSON object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

The usual .last or :last jquery selectors are not doing it for me. 
I have an object `content.object` that has HTML in it like

```
<P>
item 1
</P>
<P>
item 2
</P>
<P>
item 3
</P>
```

I have tried

```
var lastItem = $(content.object).find('p:last');
```

and

```
var lastItem = $(content.object).find('p').last();
```

But these aren't doing the trick and I keep getting errors. How can I get the text in the last

?

Comment: Is that a string? What errors are you getting?

Comment: Nothing in your question shows JSON data. You're using that term incorrectly.

Comment: it is a json object with HTML data in it. the HTML is shown. the JSON is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The find method wont work because you are already inside the same depth as the `p tags`

If your JSON object looks like this

```
var content = {
    object: '<P>item 1</P><P>item 2</P><P>item 3</P>'
};
```

You can access the last p like so:

```
var lastItem = $( content.object ).last();
```

Comment: that did it. specifically `var lastItem = $(content.object).last().text();`

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

```
var lastItem = $(content.object).filter('p:last');
```

[.filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) : Reduce the set of matched elements to those that match the selector or pass the function's test.
[.find](http://api.jquery.com/find/) : Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/YyKW8/)